# Dynamic number of fields in a meta box

Tags: metabox

I am working with a recipes blog and I use custom meta boxes.

```
$food_box = array(
    'id' => 'foodbox',
    'title' => __('Ingredients details','splus'),
    'page' => 'recipes',
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'fields' => array(),);
$arr = array ( 'name' => '-', 'desc' => '-', 'id' => '-','type' => 'text', 'std' => '');
add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_box');  // Add meta box

function mytheme_add_box() {
    global $meta_box;
    global $food_box;
    global $test_box;
    add_meta_box(
        $meta_box['id'], 
        $meta_box['title'], 
        'recipe_details_show_box', 
        $meta_box['page'], 
        $meta_box['context'], 
        $meta_box['priority']
    );
    add_meta_box(
        $food_box['id'], 
        $food_box['title'], 
        'ingredients_show_box', 
        $food_box['page'], 
        $food_box['context'], 
        $food_box['priority']
    );
}
```

Acoording to recipe ingredients are devided to sets of food and the same food item can be present 2 time in one recipe (for example, 200gr sugar for dough and 50 gr for stuff). To combine two taxonomies (food items and food sets) I created custom table and I add fileds `$food_box['fields'][] = $arr;` from this table by next code:

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) { // show tabs content for foodset
    $s = ($i==1) ? ' ': ' style="display: none;"';
    echo '<div id="set-'.$term->term_id .'" class="tabs-panel"' . $s . '>';
        echo '<ul id="set2-checklist" class="categorychecklist form-no-clear" >';
            echo '<table id="food_data_table_header" class="form-table" border="0" align="left">';
            echo '<tr>';   //show header
                echo '<td style="width: 50%" >  <span>FoodSet</span>        </td>';
                echo '<td style="width: 50%" >  <span>FoodId</span>     </td>';
                echo '<td style="width:100%" >  <span>Description</span>    </td>';
                echo '<td style="width: 50%" >  <span>FoodUnit</span>       </td>';
                echo '<td style="width: 50%" >  <span>Quantity</span>       </td>';
                echo '<td style="width: 50%" >  <span>Order</span>      </td>';
                echo '<td style="width:100%" >  <span>Comment</span>        </td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            foreach ( $foods as $food ) {       //show data
                $food_row = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare(
                    "SELECT rf.post_id, rf.foodset_id, rf.food_id, tt1.description, rf.food_unit, rf.quantity, rf.food_order, rf.food_comment
                       FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt1 JOIN $wpdb->recipefood rf ON rf.food_id = tt1.term_id
                      WHERE (rf.post_id=".$post_id.") AND (rf.foodset_id=".$term->term_id.") AND (rf.food_id=".$food->term_id.")"));
                $food_set = $term->term_id;
                $food_id = $food->term_id;
                $id = $food_set . '-' . $food_id;
                $food_name = $food_row->description;

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>',$food_set,'</td>';
    echo '<td>',$food_id,'</td>';
    echo '<td>',$food_name,'</td>';
    $fls = array ('food_unit','quantity','food_order','food_comment');
    foreach ($fls as $fl) {
        switch ($fl) {
        case 'food_unit':
        $def_val = $def_unit; break;
        case 'quantity':
        $def_val = $def_qty; break;
        case 'food_order':
        $def_val = '1'; break;
        case 'food_comment':
        $def_val = 'comment'; break;
    }
    $meta = ($food_row->$fl == '') ? $def_val : $food_row->$fl;
    $arr = array ( 'name' => $fl.'-'. $id, 'desc' => $fl.'-'. $id, 'id' => $fl.'-'. $id,'type' => 'text', 'std' => $meta);
    $food_box['fields'][] = $arr; //add new field to array
    echo '<td>','<input type="text" name="'.$fl.'-'.$id. '" id="'.$fl.'-'.$id.'" value="',$meta , '" style="width: 50%"/>', '</td>';
    // $meta ? $meta : $food_box[$fl.'-'.$id]['std']
}
echo '</tr>';
```

But unfortunately I can not save my updated data as `$_POST['quantity-708-481']` is empty and not defined in

```
add_action('save_post', 'mytheme_save_data');   // Save recipe post from meta box
function mytheme_save_data($post_id) {
        global $meta_box, $food_box;
        //...
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->recipefood,
        array( //set
            'food_comment' =>  $_POST['quantity-708-481']
        ), array( //where
            'post_id' => '1',
            'foodset_id' => '822',
            'food_id' => '484'
        ) 
    );
```

In other words, the field is added in meta box but not visible during saving.
Any suggestion are more than welcomed.

Comment: All those `$fl.'-'. $id` are quite confusing... Compare the HTML with the output of `var_dump($_POST);die();` inside the function `mytheme_save_data`. I'm voting to close as *too-localized* as this looks too much to a wrong var names problem and debugging all this is a task for you.

Comment: If you're not hard-coding the `id` when you output, you shouldn't hard-code it when you're saving as well.

Comment: I added code to show fields 'quantity-708-481', 'food_comment-708-481' etc.

Answer (score 1):

`$fl` is 'quantity', but from your code snippet it is not clear what `$id` is set to. I think it is something like `481` or `708`. So `name="'.$fl.'-'.$id. '"` will result in `quantity-481` or `quantity-708` and *not* `quantity-708-481`.

Check the HTML of your metabox if the name is what you expect (use something like FireBug in FireFox or the Developer Tools in Chrome).

Comment: I have added more code before to clarify that `quantity-708-481` or `quantity-822-484` is created right. More over, when I echo `$field['std']` for `$field['id'] == 'quantity-822-484'` in the meta box after initialization, I receive correct data from database. So, as I understand fields of meta box are added and I filled. `echo count ($food_box['fields']);` shows correct number during editing but wrong after saving.

Comment: Did you use the Developer Tools in Chrome or FireBug in FireFox? When not, why? There is a function to inspect the sended POST and GET data. Another way to inspect what was send, add `die( var_dump( $_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST ) );` as first line in `mytheme_save_data()`. This will stop the saving and displaying what was sended. But my best guess is, your fomr fields are _not_ inside the for element. Wrap your form fields with a `<form>` tag and set the method to `POST`.

Comment: Ralf912, thanks for yourinput. I will try the first suggested method. The second is not clear for me - could you give more info about "method to POST"?